# Mongoose, Find Model property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using express and mongoose to retrieve data from mongodb, when i try to query:

```
Event.find({"StartTime":{$gte:start, $lte: end }}, function(err, today){
        cb({"all":docs, "live_total": docs.length, "today":today, "today_total": today.length, "start":start, "end":end, "now":now});
    })
```

It returns results, but when i do:

```
Event.find({"League":"2399913"}, function(err, ev){
        console.log(ev)
    })
```

It returns nothing even if i do manually the query in mongodb return results:

query on mongo

```
db.events.find({"League": "50012238"});
```

results

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c02fc1a683a6595444b5d0"), "EventID" : "62332340", "League" : "50012238", "LeagueName" : "King's Cup", "Sport" : "6046", "SportName" : "Football", "Location" : "80", "LocationName" : "Saudi Arabia", "StartTime" : ISODate("2017-01-21T07:15:00Z"), "homeTeam" : "50038781", "homeTeamName" : "Al Safa (KSA)", "awayTeam" : "250417", "awayTeamName" : "Al Qadisiya", "EventStatus" : "NSY", "Active" : "I", "BookmakerTotalCnt" : "3", "Outcomes" : { "Outcome" : { "OutcomeID" : "1", "OutcomeName" : "1X2", "Bookmaker" : { "BookmakerID" : "8", "BookmakerName" : "Bet365", "BookmakerTotalOddsCnt" : "18", "Odd" : [ { "EventID" : "62332340", "LineID" : "586978", "OutcomeID" : "1", "BookmakerID" : "8", "OutcomeName" : "1X2", "BookmakerName" : "Bet365", "bet" : "1", "BaseLine" : null, "line" : null, "CurrentPrice" : "6", "isResulting" : "-", "isWinner" : "0", "OutcomeType" : "1", "DrawName" : "X", "LineInfo" : null, "LineStatus" : "Open" }, { "EventID" : "62332340", "LineID" : "586979", "OutcomeID" : "1", "BookmakerID" : "8", "OutcomeName" : "1X2", "BookmakerName" : "Bet365", "bet" : "2", "BaseLine" : null, "line" : null, "CurrentPrice" : "1.4", "isResulting" : "-", "isWinner" : "0", "OutcomeType" : "1", "DrawName" : "X", "LineInfo" : null, "LineStatus" : "Open" }, { "EventID" : "62332340", "LineID" : "586980", "OutcomeID" : "1", "BookmakerID" : "8", "OutcomeName" : "1X2", "BookmakerName" : "Bet365", "bet" : "X", "BaseLine" : null, "line" : null, "CurrentPrice" : "4.333", "isResulting" : "-", "isWinner" : "0", "OutcomeType" : "1", "DrawName" : "X", "LineInfo" : null, "LineStatus" : "Open" } ] } } } }
```

Here is my model definition:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = {};
//static method
exports.schema = function(req, res){
    return mongoose.Schema({
        Sport: Number,
        League: Number,
        LeagueName: String,
        Location: String,
        SportName: String,
        StartTime: Date,
        StartTimeJS: Date,
        LocationName: String,
        homeTeam: String,
        homeTeamName: String,
        awayTeam: String,
        awayTeamName: String,
        EventStatus: String,
        Active: Number,
        BookmakerTotalCnt: String,
        Outcomes: Array,
        EventID: Number
    });
}
```

So basically it finds by some keys but not for others, any idea?

Comment: Could it be because you have `Lueague` instead of `League`?

Comment: Was my typo on the type i wrote the post in the code is correct

Comment: Does it return any errors?

Comment: No, if i use " if(err) console.log(err) " sends nothing. so weird.

Comment: Try `League` with single quotation or without it and value as a Number.

Comment: Are you sure ` {"League":"2399913"} ` exists in your DB? Cause you're testing mongo using a different value. Also, for your last question, you probably didn't insert any values for those keys. In mongoose, you need to specify a default value for that key to be added to mongo. Otherwise, null or undefined values for keys will not be inserted.

Comment: Event.find({'League': '2399913'}, function(err, ev){ console.log(ev) }) -> Nothing

Event.find({League: 2399913}, function(err, ev){ console.log(ev) }) ;-> Nothing

Event.find({'League': 2399913}, function(err, ev){ console.log(ev) }) ;-> League

Mongo Query:

db.events.find({"League": "2399913"}).count(); = 21

Comment: Could you try `Event.find({"League":"2399913"}).exec( function(err, ev){
        console.log(ev)
    });`

Comment: (node:8772) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
ev => []

Answer (score 0):

Manually you did right query:

```
db.events.find({"League": "50012238"});
```

But in this query "U" into `"Lueague"` is wrong!

```
Event.find({"Lueague":"2399913"}, function(err, ev){
        console.log(ev)
    })
```

Try this:

```
Event.find({"League": 2399913}).exec(function(err, ev)
{ console.log(ev) });
```

Comment: Was my typo on the type i wrote the post in the code is correct

Comment: And try use this version in mongoose:
Event.find({"League": 2399913}, function(err, ev){
        console.log(ev)
    })
Because your tipe is Number not string

Comment: Try: Event.find({"League": 50012238 }, function(err, ev){
        console.log(ev)
    })
Maybe result is really empty for "2399913"?

Comment: Mongo Query: db.events.find({"League": "2399913"}).count(); = 21

Comment: Try this:
Event.find({"League": 2399913}).exec(function(err, ev){ console.log(ev) });
Take from this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you're telling Mongoose that `League` is a number, yet it seems to be stored in the database as a string.

Because of this, Mongoose runs the equivalent of this query (because Mongoose will cast the string `"2399913"` in the query to a number, so it matches the schema type):

```
db.events.find({ League : 2399913 })
```

Notice how there are no quotes around the number.

Because strings and numbers are different things, this query won't match any of the documents in your collection.

The fix would be to update your schema so `League` becomes a string:

```
League: String,
```